# How to open .py file

Tags: file-format

I downloaded an [app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=33694fad-8a1d-470c-9ad2-8aec2f7c461b) that claims it's capable of opening .py (Python) files. Whenever I try to download a .py file it first gives me the option of opening or saving it. However, the phone will then display a message claiming that it doesn't support this file type. I'm running Windows Phone 8.1 Update (Developer Preview)

Comment: Where are you downloading the python files from?

Comment: They're being sent as attachments through Facebook messenger. This opens a weblink and you download the file through IE.

Comment: It *might* be the case that the Facebook Messenger webserver isn't declaring the files as Python files, which is causing the problem...

Comment: I tried again and I think you may be right. No .py extension in the address that messenger opens in the browser. I can't help but feel this is silly that I can't download what I want, regardless of what file type it is or is declared as.

Answer (score -1):

Use this [app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=d20c26b6-813f-4b81-8c71-054d5d4bd0dd). It supports a number of languages including Python. But there is no syntax colorization available for Python in this app now. But you can ask the developer to add this feature.

Comment: I already have that app. If the file is already on my on my phone then yes, this let's me open it. The problem is that I can't even download the files using only my phone.